# 400 bad request from web api 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have a simple web api 2 controller returning an object in JSON format,
when i try to call it using an httpclient i get a bad request,but when directly pasting the url in the browser i get the correct result:

http://ipaddress/api/cov/GetViders/latitude/longitude/ works well.

http://ipaddress/GetViders/latitude/longitude/ 400 bad request.

Api controller:

```
[Route("api/cov/GetViders/{latitude}/{longitude}/")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetViders(float latitude, float longitude)
    {

      var vm = ....


        return Json(vm);
    }
```

.net client : (web controller)

```
[Route("GetViders/{latitude}/{longitude}")]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<ViderListViewModel>> GetViders(float latitude, float longitude)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            // TODO - Send HTTP requests
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://...../");

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "keep-alive");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0");

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/cov/GetViders/" + latitude + "/" + longitude + "/");

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                List<ViderListViewModel> viders = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<ViderListViewModel>>();
                return viders;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Edit:

I also tried to call the api using a webclient :

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            var json = client.DownloadString(url);
            var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            IEnumerable<ViderListViewModel> model = serializer.Deserialize<IEnumerable<ViderListViewModel>>(json);

        }
```

I got the same error : 400 bad request.

P.S.:

Even if the api and the client are two different projects, they are both located on the same server, so CORS should not be the cause of the issue, that said i have added that to make sure it's not the cause:

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

any idea what i'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Could you provide details (body) of Bad Request response?

Comment: firefox returns 400 bad request, ie return 304, chrome returns 200 with empty response.

Comment: not sure I understand this correctly, but why dont you have http://ipaddress/**api**/**con/**GetViders/latitude/longitude/ 
in this url?

Comment: since the direct url is working, everything is configured well, the issue is coming from headers but no idea which one

Comment: @Nilesh : first url is direct url to api,
second one is url to the web controller from where the api call is done

Comment: Got it. So are you getting bad request on this statement? `HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/cov/GetViders/" + latitude + "/" + longitude + "/");`
Or when you directly access `http://ipaddress/GetViders/latitude/longitude/` ?

Comment: the statement is inside the call to the web controller http://ipaddress/GetViders/latitude/longitude/

Comment: Is the `client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://...../");` baseaddress set to `http://ipaddress/`? cause I did the exact same things that you have in your code and it works absolutely fine. only difference is that I am using a console application